# В чем различие между QList::value и QList::operator[]?

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, qtableview, value

мой вопрос - в чем отличие закомментированной и следующей за ней строкой в блоке `switch`? Если закомментировать строку, где к элементу `values` идёт обращение через `operator[]`, и раскомментировать строку с обращением через `value`, то программа будет игнорировать замену `id/name/icon` у элемента массива таким образом. Помогите, пожалуйста, очень хочется понять, почему это не работает

```
class TableViewModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);

private:
    QList<Data>* values;
};

bool TableViewModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if (index.isValid() && (role == Qt::EditRole)) 
    {
        switch(index.column())
        {
            case      0: 
            {
                //values->value(index.row()).setId(value.toInt());
                (*this->values)[index.row()].setId(value.toInt());
                break;
            }
            case      1: 
            {
                //values->value(index.row()).setName(value.toString());
                (*this->values)[index.row()].setName(value.toString());
                break;
            };
            case      2: 
            {
                //values->value(index.row()).setIcon(value.toString());
                (*this->values)[index.row()].setIcon(value.toString());
                break;
            };
        }
        emit this->dataChanged(index, index);
        emit this->appendValue();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Достаточно беглого взгляда на документацию: `T value(int i) const` возвращает копию, которую вы изменяете; `T & QList::operator[](int i)` возвращает неконстантную ссылку.

Comment: Если элемента с индексом i нет в контейнере, то `value` возвращает `T{}`, а `[]` - UB.

Comment: @user207200 я тоже так думал, но не был до конца уверен

Comment: Если были сомнения, это легко было проверить сравнив адреса объектов.

Comment: @user207200 буду знать. спасибо!